# Unzipping a file on windows server 2012r2 via chef

Tags: powershell, zip, chef-infra

I am trying to unzip a file on server 2012r2 through chef. I get an error back "illegal characters in path". When I manually type the commands in the file is extracted exactly as it should, but doing it through chef it just does not want to work for some reason.

```
powershell_script 'test' do
code <<-EOH [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem") | Out-Null
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('c:\tmp\hp401n.zip', 'c:\tmp')
EOH
end
```

Comment: You get an error from which component? What else does the error message contain?

Comment: Added full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes because they are getting processed by Ruby too, `c:\\tmp\\hp401n.zip` and `C:\\tmp`. Otherwise you probably have literal tab characters (`\t`) in the path.

Comment: Ha, Finally asked my boss told me that same thing. Thanks though.